# Create case with no accountId although contact has related account

Tags: trigger, account, contact, admin

When creating case, if contact has accountId, Salesforce is automatically relating my case to that account which I would like not to happen. If account is selected on the case and contact has account related, I would like to create case with out account on it.

Here is the link where SF says "When you enter or select a contact for the Contact Name field, the Account Name field defaults to the account associated with the contact when you save the case. However, you can change the account in the Account Name field during subsequent updates."
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cases_create.htm&language=en

Is there a way to create cases with no account associated although contact has accountId present on it ?

Thanks

Comment: you could probably clear it out in an after insert trigger on Case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create an additional lookup relationship with Contact on the Case
   object
2. Use the newly created Contact field in your Pagelayout and hide the Original one.
3. Use a Workflowrule or process to update the original Contact lookup field with the Value in your newly created Contact field.

Comment: The problem is once contact is updated salesforce is automatically populating accountid on case

Comment: Only on Case creation as far as I know, not on update.

Comment: As of now, on case update, too, accountId is populated automatically.